# Ggplot not reordering variables; warning messages requires estimate means

Tags: r, ggplot2

I created a simple database with `env_var (x)` and `env_y (y)` as my independent values. When plotting ggplot automatically re-organize the variable in alphabetical order. I tried re-ordering the `env_var` by `env_y` values but it seems like the code attempts to create statistics (mean) in order to re-order as indicated by these error messages:

`In mean.default(X[[i]], ...) :argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA`

I do not need to get the means, it is a very straightforward dataset with one `env_y` values corresponding to one `env_var` variable. I read in other post that you should organize the data itself instead of using aes which is what I did before hand. I enter the variables in the order I want them be plotted. I also made sure to set `env_y` as numeric as indicated in previous post. I tried using `forcats` but it seems like this solution involves estimating means as well. Is there an argument to reorder by the raw values without performing any statistics?

*Note: I tried `geom_point()` and `geom_point(stat="identity")` arguments in case this was the problem.

```
env_var<-    c('bio6','bio15','bio18','bio12','bio5','bio1','bio17','bio19','bio9','bio7','bio8')

env_y<- c('43.4','25.2','12.1','3.7','2.8','2.7','2.7','2.3','1.8','1.7','1.7')

as.numeric(env_y)
as.factor(env_var)
env_model <- data.frame(env_var, env_y)

p <- ggplot(env_model, aes(x = reorder(env_var,env_y), y = env_y)) +
    geom_point()
p
```

Comment: you gotta do env_y <- as.numeric(env_y), otherwise it remains a character. Same for the other variable

Comment: before you put it into a data.frame, check class(env_var); class(env_y)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the points plotted by the order you define them, you must set the factor levels manually.

```
env_var <- factor(env_var, levels = env_var)
```

Then plot them but, like user [@StupidWolf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12258459/stupidwolf) says in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60421842/ggplot-not-reordering-variables-warning-messages-requires-estimate-means#comment106888267_60421842),

> you gotta do env_y <- as.numeric(env_y), otherwise it remains a
>   character.

Only then create the data.frame.

```
env_y <- as.numeric(env_y)
env_model <- data.frame(env_var, env_y)

p <- ggplot(env_model, aes(x = env_var, y = env_y)) +
  geom_point()
p
```

[image]

Try changing the factor `env_var` to any of

```
env_var <- factor(env_var)
env_var <- factor(env_var, levels = stringr::str_sort(env_var, numeric = TRUE))
```

and see the points' orders.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the solution! There were a couple of things I was doing wrong.

First, I was using '' when creating the numeric vectors so R did not recognize the env_y as numbers even when using as.numeric() argument.

Second, it seems like to reorder the dataset I had to store the ordering within the data frame as:

```
env_model$env_var <- with(env_model, reorder(env_var,-env_y))
#or 
env_model <- env_model[order(env_model$env_y, decreasing=T),]
```

This did the trick for me.